# AFNetworking code giving me Memory Leaks

Tags: ios, iphone, memory-leaks, xcode6, afnetworking-2

```
@implementation GetData

static NSString *string = @"https://afternoon-springs-7986.herokuapp.com/";
static NSString *baseStr = @"https://afternoon-springs-7986.herokuapp.com/updateInformation";    

-(void) postEventInfo: (NSDictionary *) eventInfoObject


    {
        NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:string];  // 6.5%
       // NSURL *baseURL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://localhost:5000/"];

        UIWindow *window = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] keyWindow];
        UIView *topView = window.rootViewController.view;

        self.manager = [[AFHTTPSessionManager alloc] initWithBaseURL:url]; // 71%
        self.manager.requestSerializer = [AFJSONRequestSerializer serializer];
        self.manager.responseSerializer = [AFJSONResponseSerializer serializer]; // 9.7%

        [self.manager POST:@"/addEvent/" parameters:eventInfoObject success:^(NSURLSessionDataTask *task, id responseObject) { // 12.9%

        [FVCustomAlertView showDefaultDoneAlertOnView:topView withTitle:@"Klart!"];

        } failure:^(NSURLSessionDataTask *task, NSError *error) {

        [FVCustomAlertView showDefaultErrorAlertOnView:topView withTitle:@"Ett fel uppstod, försök igen!"];
        }];
    }
```

I am receiving memory leaks on this code above. As you can see i commented the amount of % same as the Leaks instrument did. Im running Xcode 6, and the test is made on my iPhone device 5s IOS 7.1.1

Here is a screenshot of how to leaks tool was looking like.
https://www.dropbox.com/s/beh4no79wgk54bm/Screen%20Shot%202015-03-12%20at%2013.09.53.png?dl=0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Every time you call "`postEventInfo`", you're creating a `AFHTTPSessionManager` object.

If you're using ARC, this should mean the old object gets released (i.e. not such a problem).  But for best practices sake you should do something like this:

```
// set self.manager only if it hasn't been created yet
if(!self.manager)
{
    self.manager = [[AFHTTPSessionManager alloc] initWithBaseURL:url]; // 71%
    self.manager.requestSerializer = [AFJSONRequestSerializer serializer];
    self.manager.responseSerializer = [AFJSONResponseSerializer serializer]; // 9.7%
}
```

Comment: Would it be the same if i just make a property of AFHTTPSessionManager and use that in different places? Since i have another post method?

Comment: I think it should be okay, but then again, will you be calling these two posts at the same time?  From the same class / view controller?

Comment: I did as you said but it still goes in the if statement the second time so if(!self.manager) is not doing the trick

Comment: Is there any other way to see if an object has been initialised?

Comment: I guess what you are saying is true because the leak always appears the second time i call the postEvent method. But i self.manager is always nil what can the problem be?

Comment: Solved it by using the method for POST provided by the site for AFNetworking in github https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking