# AFHTTPSessionManager memory leak

Tags: ios, afnetworking

I have a subclass of AFHTTPSessionManager implemented as singleton. It has delegate property and 2 methods: get and post with required parameters. Each method calls GET or POST method of their superclass and passes data to delegate in completion handlers. Memory leaks utility shows that there is a strong cycle:
[image]

[image]

[image]

What am i doing wrong?

Comment: - Follow This link. This may help you.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29009469/afnetworking-code-giving-me-memory-leaks

Comment: @Avinash651 Thanks, but it's singleton and all i'm doing In my methods is calling GET or POST and delegate completion.